# How to find Auto-correlation of a complex Gaussian integral

Tags: probability-theory, order-statistics

I have a 1D function $h_1$  and would like to find the the autocorrelation given as follows:

[image: autocorrelation]

Also, $h_1$ is defined as:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I am stuck as I don't know how to solve this complex gaussian integral.

Can You please comment on my derivation of auto-correlation:
[Derivation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9FkRPI6OUN8cTgzRnBXc0J5MUU)

Comment: The product of two gaussian is a gaussian.

Comment: Hi, can I use the following identity to find the expectation:

Comment: According to Wikipedia page (if you scroll down) on gaussian integral E[exp(-ax^2)]=sqrt(pi/a)(2pi-1)!!/(2a)^n;  but I am not sure as it doesn't say anything whether ''a'' can be imaginary.

Comment: It can be complex with real part $> 0$